# How to Assign User Permission Via CheckboxList Using MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, user-permissions

I'm attempting to grant user permission via MERN using a checkbox list; I've already attempted to grant manual user access by using an if and else statement to grant fixed authorization. Here's an illustration:

```
 {user.role == "SuperAdmin" || user.role == "Admin" ? (
                <>
                  {/* Users */}
                  <PrivateRoute path="/admin/users" component={Users} exact />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    path="/admin/users/create"
                    component={AddUser}
                    exact
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    path="/admin/users/edit/:id"
                    component={EditUser}
                    exact
                  />
              ) : (
                <div id="notfound">
                  <div class="notfound">
                    <div class="notfound-404">
                      <h1>Oops!</h1>
                    </div>
                    <h2>404 - You are not Authorized</h2>
                    <p>
                      The page you are looking for might have been removed had
                      its name changed or you are not authorized to access this
                      page.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#">Go To Homepage</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
```

As you can see I used if and else statement in the route, are there any packages tutorial or any sample code you could give me to assign user permission using checkbox list with MERN, thank you all for your help your answers will deeply be appreciated. :)

Here is what i wanted:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create a kind of user permission management page? or Do you want to ensure that only specific users can access to /react-route1 , /react-route2, etc ?

Comment: @JRichardsz Yes, a user permission management page

Comment: Please could you add a screen of your required form? For example, check this page http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.com/2014/11/access-control-concept-in-pentaho.html in which we can see the classic user creation, roles and operation management. Is this what you need?

Comment: If you're looking to create a user permissions/roles management app, then take a look at this very detailed post - https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/28/nodejs-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api. The author also has a very detailed post on the frontend that uses this Node backend - https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/01/react-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example

Comment: I mean making user management page where u can give permission using checkboxlist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add some condition like

```
{user && user !=null && user.role &&(user.role == "SuperAdmin" || user.role == "Admin")? (-- your if code) : (---your else code)};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I wanted via checkboxlist giving user permission like create user check

Comment: You are comparing 2 strings so when it comes to javascript the comparison statement should be **user.role === "SuperAdmin"** instead of **user.role == "SuperAdmin"** using triple equal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to contact the server when you make a request from one of the private routes. You can send a post/patch update from there via Axios. We need to see what's going on within the components to help you with your checkbox problem.